# Css Style unit testing in jasmine

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, enzyme, jasmine2.0

how to unit test  css of a node in enzyme

.toHaveStyle() is not working for me

any other enzyme matcher to test the css?

[this](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers) is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. As I was thinking that `.toHaveStyle()` will also check for the css which is inside the class

like `<p class="hello" style="color:yellow">hello</p>`

```
.hello{
padding:5px
}
```

the `.toHaveStyle()` will only check the style `prop`.